# Newest question list of [regex] showing old questions on first few pages

Tags: bug, newest-questions

For some weird reason, the 2nd and 3rd page of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) (newest tab) is filled with old questions at the end of the page (the top of the page looks normal):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?page=3&sort=newest&pagesize=50
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=50

Here is a screenshot for the 3rd page:

> [image: Questions from '08]

I made sure to do a hard refresh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and the same thing is shown.

I only observe this for these 2 pages. Other pages (and even on other tags) don't seem to be affected.

---

**2014-02-28 19:01:00**

This happens again, but this time on the 1st page of [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) newest tab. I know this is due to caching, but it makes it hard to browse the list of questions for some time. Would you please track down the cause of this issue?

Comment: The server side cache gets mangled like that sometimes, it happens pretty often and sorts itself out at some point.